# Routes URL helper leading to example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, urlhelper

**Mailer file**

```
button_to 'YES', lender_accept_url(borrow), method: :post, id: "accept #{borrow.id}", style: "background-color:green; color: white; width: 40px; display: inline"
button_to 'NO', lender_decline_url(borrow), method: :post, id: "decline #{borrow.id}", style: "background-color:gray; width: 40px; display: inline"
```

**Routes**

```
post 'inventories/:id/accept', to: 'inventories#accept', as: 'lender_accept'
post 'inventories/:id/decline', to: 'inventories#decline', as: 'lender_decline'
```

However, when I click a button in the email, it takes me to `http://example.com/inventories/:id/decline`

Why is the URL helper not leading to my own domain? Note, this same partial used in the Mailer file is also used in a regular view page, and on that page, the routes work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailers are divorced from the http request/response cycle: they don't know what the current request is (much like your models), and thus what the current host is. They might not be even used from a request (for example if your emails are sent from a cronjob). On the other hand  your views can look at the current request to know what the current host so that's why they generate the correct url.

There are 2 ways of solving this:

You can set

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "example.com" }
```

in application.rb or the per environment files.

Alternatively set the host explicitly when you call the URL helpers. This would require whoever is sending the email to pass the desired host to the mailer (using `request.host` for example). The mailer would store this in an instance variable, for example `@host` and then in your view you would use

```
lender_accept_url(borrow, host: @host)
```

The downside of this is that sharing views/partials with regular controller actions would require you to set @host there too.

As a halfway house approach  you should also be able to set `default_url_options` on a per instance attribute